# I am trying to route pug file in Express. The page rendered in not from view folder

Tags: node.js, express

[text]This is the code I have in index.js file in the root folder in Express Project Folder[text]

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var app = express();
app.set("views",path.join(__dirname,"views"));
app.set("view engine","pug");
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render("sachin");
});

app.listen(3010);
console.log('Server is running on port 3010...');
```

[text] So in view folder I have made a file sachin.pug but its not rendering that file. [text]

Answer (score 0):

Ohh Sorry guys , I dint know that to render page , we have to again restart server
After writing $node index , it rendered the page.